# Django UserPassesTestMixin, Looping error in get_absolute_url?

Tags: python, django

**Views.py**

```
class ProfileCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = ProfileForm
    template_name = "profile/profile_new.html"
    slug_field = "username"

    def get_login_url(self):
        return reverse('account_login')

    def test_func(self):
        a = self.request.user.username
        # print (a)
        b = self.kwargs['slug']
        # print (b)
        x = self.get_object().full_name
        # print (x)
        y = ''
        if a == b:
            if x == y:
                return True
        else:
            def get_absolute_url(self):
                return reverse('profile:view_profile', kwargs={"slug": self.request.user.username})


class ProfileEdit(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = ProfileForm
    template_name = "profile/profile_new.html"
    slug_field = "username"

    def get_login_url(self):
        return reverse('account_login')

    def test_func(self):
        a = self.request.user.username
        #print (a)
        b = self.kwargs['slug']
        #print (b)
        x = self.get_object().full_name
        #print (x)
        y = ''
        if a == b:
            if x != y:
                return True
        else:
            def get_absolute_url(self):
                print("failing")
                return reverse('profile:profile_view', kwargs={"slug": self.request.user.username})
```

**Explanation**
The LoginRequiredMixin forces the user to login.
UserPassesTestMixin checks

1. if full_name is ''(empty)
2. if the loggedin user's username is same as the slug field

The `test_func()` is all correct when it returns True, but in the `else`loop ie., if the test condition fails the view should redirect to 'profile_view' but it does not do so. i get the output `"failing"` in the terminal. only when i do the same inside the `get_absolute_url()` function it does not work. The complete `get_absolute_url()` function does not work. What am i doing wrong here?

**note:** the total process seems to be in a loop here

1. GET /user1/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
2. GET /as/login/?next=/user1/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

these two URLS keep looping.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have `get_absolute_url` inside the `test_func` method. The method should return either `True` or `False`.

Comment: so what do i do to redirect to a view is the `test_func()` returns `False`

Comment: The mixin will redirect to [`login_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin.login_url) if the `user_passes_test` mixin returns `False`. Your case is trickly because the `LoginRequiredMixin` and `UserPassesTestMixin` will both check `login_url`. You might have to override [`get_login_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin.get_login_url) instead.

Comment: i did the same 
`def get_login_url(self):
        return reverse('account_login')` i get the same looping problem. is there  a better way to do it?

Comment: If you've changed the code, then please [edit] your question. At the moment, the nested `get_absolute_url` is very confusing.

Comment: To give a simple Understanding. when the user register's the `full_name` field is empty, so i want the user to access the `ProfileCreate` view only for the first time when the user logs in and if the user has `full_name` already. then he must not be allowed to access `ProfileCreate` view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142753/discussion-between-rahul-and-alasdair).

Comment: thought of a better logic. Thanks